# What's the tax rate on Roth IRA contributions for a nonresident alien?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, non-resident

I am considering open a Roth IRA account and I was wondering how much I'll be taxed on my deposits. I am a nonresident alien for tax purposes, and I read online that I would be subject to a 30% rate. This is about twice the tax rate I pay from my wages, so it seems excessive. I would appreciate any information on this!

Thanks!

Comment: For a NR, unless you're planning on getting a green card and emigrating into the US, Roth is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, I've been in the US as a student for 4 years and I am planning to stay and get a green card as soon as I can apply for one.

Answer (score 6):

Roth deposits are made with post tax money. It's not like there's a special rate. When you earn a dollar, it's taxed at your marginal rate but at that moment, it doesn't know your plans for it.